# jQuery UI draggable/droppable flicker

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, flicker

I'm using this code: http://jsfiddle.net/JoeyMorani/7LWj4/
Seems that the code I've written has an error somewhere and is causing the divs to flicker when quickly dragging them. They flicker to the original position and then back to where you're dragging.

If you try dragging the div '1' quickly to the droppable div next to it, you'll see the flicker. Happens in Firefox more than Chrome. Haven't tried IE yet.

Any ideas what's causing it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ahh, turns out it was this:

```
ui.draggable.animate({
    top: '+=' + top_end,
    left: '+=' + left_end
});
```

Adding a duration to the animation has fixed the flicker:

```
ui.draggable.animate({
    top: '+=' + top_end,
    left: '+=' + left_end
},200);
```

Thanks anyway! :)